# auto enclose word under cursor with {} () []

Tags: braces, insert

Usually I would like to enclose the word under cursor with `[`, `]`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}` by simply selecting the word (select mode or visual mode) and typing `[` (or `{`, `)`), for example resulting to:

`hello` to `[hello]`.

To do this I quickly wrote this function:

```
function! EncloseSBraces()
   let l:sword = @*
   let l:cLine = line('.')
   let l:cCol = col('.')
   silent! exec ":.s/".l:sword."/[".l:sword."]/"
   call cursor(l:cLine, l:cCol)
endfunction

snoremap <silent> <nowait> [ <C-o>:call EncloseSBraces()<CR>
```

wich does the job except for 2 things: 1) if the word I would like to enclose is repeated more than once in the line, as default the function will always enclose the first occurrence of the word and not the one I have selected (e.g. if I selected the second one).
So if the line is

`hello hello`

it will be:

`[hello] hello`

always.. And 2), it does not take into account a multiline selected text..

So it is easy to understand that I should insert the characters at certain columns offsets...

Actually I don't find any precoocked function that would help to do so with minimum effort.

So does exist a function that could help me on this?
I looked at `append()` and `insert()` but it seems they are not of much help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you start out with a visual selection, it might be easiest to go with it. The following mapping will delete the selection, insert an opening bracket, the text just cut with `c` followed by a closing bracket. Then return to normal mode.

```
vnoremap <nowait> [ c[<C-R>"]<Esc>
```

This mapping will clobber the default register as a minor caveat. You could specify another register to make it use that one.

You were specifically asking for a function, this isn't one. Although I doubt it could be made much shorter using functions.

For the general case, take a look at Tim Pope's [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin.

Comment: +1 for vim-surround

Answer (score 3):

The `:s` command, without arguments, does a substitution for the first occurrence in a particular line; that is why the first occurrence of the selected word gets surrounded.

### Matching Visual Area

We could modify the regex to search within the visual selection only, with `/\%V`. From the help:

> `\%V`   Match inside the Visual area.  When Visual mode has already been
> stopped match in the area that |gv| would reselect.
> This is a |/zero-width| match.

Hence, in the function, the search and replace could be modified to:

```
function! EncloseSBraces()
   let l:sword = @*
   let l:cLine = line('.')
   let l:cCol = col('.')
   silent! exec ':.s/\%V'.l:sword."/[".l:sword."]/"
   call cursor(l:cLine, l:cCol)
endfunction
```

Note that to include visual mode, one should use `vnoremap` instead of `snoremap`.

```
vnoremap <silent> <nowait> [ <C-o>:call EncloseSBraces()<CR>
```

### Multiline text

With `\%V`, there is now no need to explicitly restrict the command to the line; that is, the `.` in `:.s` can be dropped. In fact, this can be replaced with `:%s`.

We modify the search to include the whole visual area: `/\%V\_.\+\%V.`,
where,

- `.\+` allows for one or more of any character
- `\_.\+` allows for multiline text
- `\%V\_.\+\%V` selects the whole visual selection, minus the last character
- `\%V\_.\+\%V.` selects the whole visual selection, including the last character.

We can use `&` in the replacement text, to refer to the last searched text.

Thus, the line

```
silent! exec ':%s/\%V\_.\+\%V./[&]/'
```

would enclose the visually selected text in `[` and `]`.

There is now no need for `l:sword`, and the function is:

```
function! EncloseSBraces()
   let l:cLine = line('.')
   let l:cCol = col('.')
   silent! exec ':%s/\%V\_.\+\%V./[&]/'
   call cursor(l:cLine, l:cCol)
endfunction

vnoremap <silent> <nowait> [ <Cmd>:call EncloseSBraces()<CR>
```

For more, see

- `:h /\_`
- `:h :&`
- `:h /\%V`

Answer (score 2):

First of all thanks everyone for the suggestions.

Following the elegant solution by [Friedrich](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/4866/friedrich) I ended up with this one:

```
xnoremap <silent> <nowait> [ di[<C-r><C-o>*]
xnoremap <silent> <nowait> { di{<C-r><C-o>*}
xnoremap <silent> <nowait> ( di(<C-r><C-o>*)
snoremap <silent> <nowait> { {<C-r><C-o>*}
snoremap <silent> <nowait> [ [<C-r><C-o>*]
snoremap <silent> <nowait> ( (<C-r><C-o>*)
```

Comment: `di` is best replaced with `s`.

Comment: Thank you for the praise. Glad you found something that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

With the mentioned [surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround), the Visual mode command is `S]`, or `ysiw]` in Normal mode

Answer (score 2):

```
noremap <nowait> ' :s/\(\%V.*\%V.\)/"\1"<cr>:noh<cr>
```

(or another binding like ')
(replace the "\1" to [\1], {\1}, (\1) to enclose with braces)

replace the marked word to "word"

`Sample w|ord to enclose.`
(| = Cursor)

<kbd>viw</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd>

`Sample "word" to enclose.`

But the cursor was at the begin of the line!

Use

```
noremap <nowait> ' mz:s/\(\%V.*\%V.\)/"\1"<cr>:noh<cr>`z
```

to mark the position to register `z` and set the cursor to the old position.

Please note: this is the binding for the standard mode (very no magic). See `:h magic`